# CakePHP Span Tag within Anchor Tag

Tags: html, css, cakephp

I'm trying to have CakePHP output a link that looks like this:

```
 <a href="/foo/bar" class="some other classes">
     <span class="icon new"></span>FooBar</a>
```

So I use the following code in my view

```
    <?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
$this->Html->tag('span', null, array('class' => 'icon new')) . "FooBar",
        array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'),
        array('class' => 'some other  classes', 'escape' => false)
     );
?>
```

However CakePHP outputs the following:

```
<a href="/foo/bar" class="some other classes">
     <span class="icon new">FooBar</span></a>
```

Which breaks my design. How can I get CakePHP to append "FooBar" *after* the `<span>` tags?

EDIT: Its also worth mentioning that I know a `<span>` tags shouldn't be within an anchor tag usually, but in the case its a must.

Comment: IMO span tags are perfectly fine within an `<a>` tag!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an empty string in stead of `null` as the text for the span, then your code will work as expected.

Looking at the source code of the HtmlHelper, `null` is treated as a 'special' value, causing only the opening tag of the span to be created. You can see this in this line:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.2/lib/Cake/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php#L906

Change your code to this and it should work;

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('span', '', array('class' => 'icon new')) . "FooBar",
    array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'),
    array('class' => 'some other  classes', 'escape' => false)
);
```

### Additional explanation of the closing `</span>`

A bit of explanation, for those who wonder:

The *closing* `</span>` in your example is actually **not present** in the output generated by CakePHP, but automatically 'added' by your browser. If you view the **source** of the HTML in your browser, you'll see that this is what is actually in your HTML:

```
<a href="/foo/bar" class="some other classes">
 <span class="icon new">FooBar</a>
```

As you can see, *no closing 'span'*

Because the `<span>` is not closed, the browser will try to correct this error and automatically assumes that you 'forgot' to close it. Therefor it will add a closing `</span>` before the next tag it finds (in this case the closing `</a>`).

The 'inspector' in your browser will always show the HTML that the browser *uses* to render the output. This includes automatic corrections made by the browser *and* dynamically generated elements (e.g. Elements added via JavaScript).

**To check the output of your PHP scripts, always view the *source*, not the inspector**

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, I've avoided the CakePHP helpers entirely because the markup becomes really messy and cannot take advantage of autocomplete or validation within your IDE.

I usually do something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'myController', 'action'=>'index'))?>"><span class="icon-new"></span>Foobar</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks a little overkill for me. Just do this:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
   "<span class="icon new"></span> FooBar",
    array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'),
    array('class' => 'some other  classes', 'escape' => false)
);
```

I've been using CakePHP for 4 years and I don't see the benefit of using tag in this instance.

Comment: I do agree with you on this one, in simple situations like this, I think I'd opt for your approach as well. I decided to base my answer on the code of the OP (which was basically correct, apart from some 'magic' Cake treatment of null values) and explain *why* it wasn't working.

Answer (score -3):

Would you be able to use regular PHP in this case?

I am thinking you could do it like this:

```
<?PHP
   echo('<a href="' . '/foo/bar' . '" class="' . 'some other classes' . '"><span class="' . 'icon new' . '"></span>' . 'FooBar' . '</a>')
?>
```

Comment: In such case he could simply make the whole webpage in HTML. What's the point of framework then?

Comment: Using textual URLs is definitely **not** the way to go in CakePHP as you won't make use of (Reverse) Routing, i.e. `/foo/bar/` will always be `/foo/bar` even if you create a special Route for this action.