# How to add content inside link in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I would like to have content inside my link with cakephp. I know I can use this syntax to have an image inside my link

```
$this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", [
                   "alt" => "Brownies",
                   'url' => ['controller' => 'Recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6]
                   ]);
```

For an HTML output like this :

```
<a href="/recipes/view/6">
   <img src="/img/recipes/6.jpg" alt="Brownies" />
</a>
```

But the above code idn't quite what I'm looking for. I would like to have the following HTML output

```
<a href="/recipes/view/6">
    <div>
        <img src="/img/recipes/6.jpg" alt="Brownies" />
    </div>
</a>
```

I came with this code witch could work but I will have to figure out the full path link.

```
<a href="<?= '/recipes/view/6' ?>">
    <div>
        <?= $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", ["alt" => "Brownies"]); ?>
    </div>
</a>
```

Is there a more robust way of doing what I want with cakephp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a more robust way, but you could possibly do something like this:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Html->link(
        $this->Html->div(null, $this->Html->image('/img/recipe/6.jpg')), 
        array('controller' => 'recipes','action' => 'view', 6), 
        array('escape' => false)
    );
?>
```

And the output would be this:

```
<a href="/recipes/view/6">
    <div>
        <img alt="" src="/img/recipes/6.jpg">
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Do you know how I can add another element inside the div? I should have included this upfront in my question, sorry. This is exactly what I was looking for, it doesn't hard code the link so it fits my need perfectly

Comment: Cakephp support the creation of DIVs, so you could add this near the image tag.. `$this->Html->div(null, 'new div element') . $this->Html->image('/img/recipe/6.jpg')`

Comment: with your comment and this question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989096/cakephp-span-tag-within-anchor-tag) I figured it out. Thank you very mutch

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Link` or `URL` mechanism.

> Using **Link**

```php
echo $this->Html->link( 
        $this->Html->div(null, 
                         $this->Html->image('recipes/6.jpg', ['alt' => 'Brownies'])), 
        array('controller' => 'Recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6), 
        array('escape' => false)
);
```

> Using **URL**

Adding the URL inside the HTML

```php
<a href="<?= $this->Html->url( array('controller' => 'Recipes', 'action' => 'view', 6), 
                               array('escape' => false)); ?>" class="light_blue">
  <div>
        <?= $this->Html->image("recipes/6.jpg", ["alt" => "Brownies"]); ?>
  </div>

</a>
```